# Shape Operator $S_n (x) = - (\bar{\nabla}_xN)^t$

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

This is from page 128 from Da Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.

> let $p \in M$, $x \in T_p M$ and $\eta \in (T_p M)^\perp.$ Let $N$ be a local extension of $n$ normal to $M$. Then $$S_n (x) = - (\bar{\nabla}_xN)^t$$

His proof goes like this

> Let $y \in T_pM$ and $X,Y$ be local extensions of $x,y$ which are tangent to $M$. Then $(N,Y) = 0$, therefore.
> $(S_n(X),y) = (B(X,Y)(p),N) = (\bar{\nabla}_X Y - \bar{\nabla}Y,N)(p) = (\bar{\nabla}_X Y, N)(p) = -(Y,\bar{\nabla}_XN)(p) = (-\bar{\nabla}_x N,y)$
> for all $y \in T_pM$.

I don't understand the last equality $-(Y,\bar{\nabla}_XN)(p) = (-\bar{\nabla}_x N,y)$

1. Is he evaluating at $p$ so we are back to the vectors $x$ and $y$? Then why do we still have $N$ and not $n$?
2. How does this show the result? The claim is that it is equal to the tangent of the derivative. It is important that $\nabla_XY = (\bar{\nabla}_{\bar{X}}\bar{Y})^t$
3. Elementary question, but I thought covariant derivative is always in the direction of a vector field not a single vector? So what is meant by $\nabla_x$?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, he's evaluating $-\langle Y, \overline{\nabla}_{X} N \rangle$ at $p$. This equals $-\langle Y(p), (\overline{\nabla}_{X} N)(p) \rangle = -\langle y, (\overline{\nabla}_{X} N)(p) \rangle $. Now, remember that given any affine connection $\nabla$, $(\nabla_X Y)(p)$ depends only on $X(p)$ and on the values of $Y$ along a curve $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(0) = p$ and $\alpha'(0) = X(p) = x$. So it makes perfect sense to let $\nabla_x Y$ (which is a tangent vector in $T_p M$) be shorthand for $(\nabla_X Y)(p)$, which is what he's doing. However, $(\nabla_X Y)(p)$ depends on $X(p)$ *and* on the values of $Y$ along a tangent curve which satifies what I wrote before. It does not depend only on $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$. That's why writing $\nabla_x y$ wouldn't make sense, and that's why we still have $N$ instead of $n$.
2. We just have to write a little more. Notice that if you write $\overline{\nabla}_X Y = \left(\overline{\nabla}_X Y  \right)^{\perp} +\left(\overline{\nabla}_X Y  \right)^{T}  $, he actually proved that:

$$\langle S_{\eta}(x), y \rangle = \left\langle - \left(\overline{\nabla}_X Y  \right)^{T}, y  \right\rangle \text{ for all $x, y \in T_p M$ }$$

And since by the properties of a Riemannian metric a tangent vector is uniquely determined by it's inner products with the whole tangent space (actually just a basis would be enough), we get the desired result.

3. You're right, it's an abuse of notation. But given what I mentioned in 1., this is a completely harmless abuse.

Comment: 2. $N \in (TM)^\perp$, $X \in TM$, so where is $\nabla_X N$? How is this even defined? I thought Affine connection takes inputs two inputs from $\Gamma(M) \times \Gamma(M)$, how can it be $\Gamma(M) \times \Gamma(M)^\perp$? Note your $Y=N$ here.

Comment: @Hawk $\nabla_X N$ is not defined, it indeed doesn't make sense, since $N$ is not a tangent vector field to the submanifold. Just replace $\nabla$ 
 for $\overline{\nabla}$ everywhere I wrote, I was just lazy and didn't think it would confuse you.

Comment: OKay so what you are saying is that $\bar{\nabla}: (X, N) \to \bar{\nabla}_XN \in \bar{TM}$ and this is okay because both $X$ and $N$ belong to $\Gamma(\bar{M})$ as it is the "ambient space". Hence $((\bar{\nabla}_XN)^\perp, y) = 0$ hence we only have the tangent component?

Comment: @Hawk Yes, that's exactly right!